# For which functions $f$ is $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus

Classically, for $0<\alpha<1$ the fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ is given by:
$$
D^{\alpha}f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x 
\frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^{\alpha}}\,dt$$
When $\alpha=0$ we can extend this to get
$$
D^0f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt
$$For *continuous* $f$, this reduces to $f(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However, this expression is undefined for functions like $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ or non-integrable functions. This feels weird: even if a function $f$ isn't differentiable, taking zero derivatives feels like we aren't 'doing anything' to $f$ and so I would expect to get $D^0$ to act as an identity, as in $ D^0 f(x)=f(x)$ for any $f$. However, the formula would seem to suggest that only integrable $f$ satisfy $f^{(0)}=f$. Can these views be reconciled?

Comment: By definition $$f^{(0)}(x)=f(x)$$

Comment: So you define $D^0$ as the identity for *any* $f$ just to avoid this wrinkle?

Comment: Well if [this is true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0th+derivative+mobius%28x%29). According to Wolfram $μ^{(0)}(x)=μ(x)$ where appears the discrete möbius function.

Comment: If you interpret a function as the distribution associated to it and take the derivative in the sense of distribution theory as well, then indeed $f \mapsto f^{(0)}$ is the identity where it is defined.

Comment: @Ian if you wrote that up as an answer with sources, I'd probably accept it :)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but in I. Podlubny's Fractional Differential Equations, he discusses the definition of $D^{0}$ as the limit $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0^{+}} D^{\alpha}$ and requires continuity of $f(t)$ for this to hold. From his construction, I recall it isn't true in general that $D^{m}D^{n} = D^{m+n}$ and requires that $f(t)$ is continuously differentiable to get many basic results.  He further mentions that the Caputo fractional derivative does not have this wrinkle. The details you are looking for may be contained within, but it's been a long time since I read his book.

Comment: (1) it is perfectly well defined for $\mathbf 1_{\Bbb Q}$ with the Lebesgue integral; the answer is zero. (2) Of course, if you use an integral to define something, it requires the function to be integrable. Its not very different from asking why $f(x) := (x-1)/(x-1)$ is undefined at $x=1$ (3) the formula holds a.e. for [AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) functions; (4) I would expect Echan's $D^0$ to differ from yours